# How to insert line breaks in a PDF generated with XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am generating a PDF using XSL-FO and XML. In a textbox, the user can enter data like "1", then he presses ENTER, then "2", ENTER, "3", etc. But in the XML and hence in the PDF, the output is "1234567". How can I preserve the line breaks? I already tried `white-space-collapse`, `linefeed-treatment` and `white-space-treatment` but that didn't help.

My XSL looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="AddCmt">
    <fo:block keep-together="always"> Additional Comments 
        <fo:block-container border-style="solid" height="20mm" width="170mm" space-after="5mm"> 
            <fo:block> 
                <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="../CMT_ID"/> 
                </xsl:attribute> 
                <xsl:value-of select="../ANS_CMT"/> 
            </fo:block> 
        </fo:block-container> 
    </fo:block> 
</xsl:template>
```

When I enter the following:

```
hello
medhavi
saraswat
```

This is the XML I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='e:\tmm-09.3\src\pmod\WorkOrder.xsl'?>
    <Root>
        <WorkOrders>
            <Detail>Id="ANS_436‌​_FLD_1" Label="qq">qq</Detail>
            <Ans Checked="0" Id="ANS_436_FLD_2" Label="ww">ww</Ans>
            <ID>ANS_436_FLD</ID>
            <ANS_FLD>0|0</ANS_FLD>
            <CMT_ID>ANS_436_CMT‌​</CMT_ID>
            <ANS_CMT>hello medhavi saraswat</ANS_CMT>
            <Warning>
                <Line>warning 11</Line>
                <Line>22</Line>
                <Line>33</Line>
                <Line>44</Line>
                <Line></Line>
                <Line>66</Lin‌​e>
                <Line>77</Line>
                <Line></Line>
            </Warning>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what FO processor you're using, and what you're xsl looks like now? It should work with those attributes you mention.

Comment: Also, you mention it is already "123456" (without linebreaks) in the XML. Then all those attributes will of course do nothing. How are you retrieving the text entered by the user (which language, application, ...) Provide some code to clarify.

Comment: the XSL looks like :   <xsl:template match="AddCmt">
    <fo:block keep-together="always">
      Additional Comments
    <fo:block-container border-style="solid" height="20mm" width="170mm" space-after="5mm">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="../CMT_ID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="../ANS_CMT"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work with the following xml (you should add all the attributes):

```
<xsl:template match="AddCmt">
    <fo:block keep-together="always"> Additional Comments 
        <fo:block-container border-style="solid" height="20mm" width="170mm" space-after="5mm"> 
            <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve"> 
                <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="../CMT_ID"/> 
                </xsl:attribute> 
                <xsl:value-of select="../ANS_CMT"/> 
            </fo:block> 
        </fo:block-container> 
    </fo:block> 
</xsl:template>
```

But as I mentioned in the comments, if your XML already has no linebreaks, there's no way your PDF will. You mentioned in your question there are no linebreaks in your XML, hence no linebreaks in the PDF.

Try checking out why there are no linebreaks in the XML. If you can provide any more information (a piece of your XML, the code you use to construct the XML, ...), please edit your answer and add the information.

Comment: Hello Peter , you are right that my XML has no line breaks and hence pdf should not have . but how come its possible that when same XMl without having line breaks , when used to display in a html based page will be properly displaying the line breaks and while displaying in pdf its giving No line breaks ?

Comment: one more thing i found is: rightclick-viewsource - xml contains page break , but when same xml is doubleclick and open in IE it wont contains any tags and also no line breaks

Comment: Aha, don't view your XML in IE as it won't show you the exact XML source. Use an editor like Notepad++. Does it have actual blank lines, or does it have special characters like &#10; ? Please edit your question and add the XML (or a relevant part of it).

Comment: Please don't enter your XML as a comment (it's unreadable). You might want to read up on how StackOverflow works. This is not a traditional forum. You can edit your question and add stuff (with markup, something you can't do in comments). Under your question (but above the comments) is an 'edit' link. Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask