# Inserting line breaks in a PDF generated with XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am generating a PDF using XSL-FO and XML. In a textbox, the user can enter data like "1", then he presses ENTER, then "2", ENTER, "3", etc. But in PDF, the output is "1234567". How can I preserve the line breaks? I already tried *white-space-collapse*, *linefeed-treatment*, and *white-space-treatment* but that didn't help. Line feed (enters) are coming in XML although.

```
<xsl:template match="AddCmt">
<fo:block keep-together="always"> Additional Comments 
    <fo:block-container border-style="solid" height="20mm" width="170mm" space-after="5mm"> 
        <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve"> 
            <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="../CMT_ID"/> 
            </xsl:attribute> 
            <xsl:value-of select="../ANS_CMT"/> 
        </fo:block> 
    </fo:block-container> 
</fo:block>
```

Comment: <xsl:template match="AddCmt">
    <fo:block keep-together="always"> Additional Comments 
        <fo:block-container border-style="solid" height="20mm" width="170mm" space-after="5mm"> 
            <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve"> 
                <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="../CMT_ID"/> 
                </xsl:attribute> 
                <xsl:value-of select="../ANS_CMT"/> 
            </fo:block> 
        </fo:block-container> 
    </fo:block> 
</xsl:template>

Comment: What is the point of the comment above?

Comment: This question seems to be a (less complete) duplicate of this one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294398/how-to-insert-line-breaks-in-a-pdf-generated-with-xsl-fo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting a line break in a PDF generated from XSL FO using <xsl:value-of>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661483/inserting-a-line-break-in-a-pdf-generated-from-xsl-fo-using-xslvalue-of)

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the following xml (you should add all the attributes):

```
<xsl:template match="AddCmt">
    <fo:block keep-together="always"> Additional Comments 
        <fo:block-container border-style="solid" height="20mm" width="170mm" space-after="5mm"> 
            <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve"> 
                <xsl:attribute name="id"> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="../CMT_ID"/> 
                </xsl:attribute> 
                <xsl:value-of select="../ANS_CMT"/> 
            </fo:block> 
        </fo:block-container> 
    </fo:block> 
</xsl:template>
```

If your XML already has no linebreaks, there's no way your PDF will.